# php how to get values of elements with google play scraper?

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

I am using google play scraper API calling html inputs and get their values 
the problem is that there is 2 html inputs having the same name classes, so when I give the path pointing to theme I get the same result for both , 
I am facing this conflict of classes when I am giving the path to Installs html input and Updated html input , this is the php code that I am using to call 
the Installs html input :

```
$downloadsNode = $crawler->filter('.xyOfqd > .hAyfc > .htlgb > div > span ');
        if ($downloadsNode->count()) {
            $downloads = trim($downloadsNode->text());
        } else {
            $downloads = null;
        }
```

and as result I Get the Updated field value cause it shares the same classes name.

this is the Html code source :

```
<div class="JHTxhe"><div class="xyOfqd"><div class="hAyfc"><div class="BgcNfc">Updated</div><span class="htlgb"><div><span class="htlgb">May 3, 2018</span></div></span></div><div class="hAyfc"><div class="BgcNfc">Size</div><span class="htlgb"><div><span class="htlgb">Varies with device</span></div></span></div><div class="hAyfc"><div class="BgcNfc">Installs</div><span class="htlgb"><div><span class="htlgb">1,000,000,000+</span></div></span></div><div class="hAyfc"><div class="BgcNfc">Current Version</div><span class="htlgb"><div><span class="htlgb">Varies with device</span></div></span></div><div class="hAyfc"><div class="BgcNfc">Requires Android</div><span class="htlgb"><div><span class="htlgb">Varies with device</span></div></span></div><div class="hAyfc"><div class="BgcNfc">Content Rating</div><span class="htlgb"><div><span class="htlgb"><div>Rated for 12+</div><div>Parental Guidance Recommended</div><div><a href="https://support.google.com/googleplay?p=appgame_ratings">Learn More</a></div></span></div></span></div><div class="hAyfc"><div class="BgcNfc">Interactive Elements</div><span class="htlgb"><div><span class="htlgb">Users Interact, Digital Purchases</span></div></span></div><c-wiz jsrenderer="HwUY7e" jsshadow="" jsdata="deferred-i23" data-p="%.@.[&quot;com.google.android.youtube&quot;,7]
]
```

could you pls help me on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved this Issue , I have added eq() function and it solved my problem .

```
$downloadsNode = $crawler->filter('.xyOfqd > .hAyfc > .htlgb > div > span')->eq(2);
```